# Как получить списки установленных программ через консоль в домене?

Tags: cmd, безопасность, консоль, администрирование

Бьемся над такой проблемой.
Много компьютеров в домене, нужно получить список установленных программ с каждой.
Сетевые диски у компов с разными буквами, соответственно запустить скрипт с одного места не получается. Пробовал через psexec запустить программу psinfo - не получается, потому что должен быть весь пакет программ. Пробовал через WMIC , но проблема при запуске, зависает и дальше ничего не происходит. Пока получилось через psexec подключиться к консоли удаленного компьютера.

Comment: *Сетевые диски у компов с разными буквами, соответственно запустить скрипт с одного места не получается.* Ну так используйте UNC-пути - им пофиг на какую букву повешен ресурс (и повешен ли вообще). Опять же (осообенно если пакет не умеет работать с использованием UNC) никто не мешает скопировать нужный пакет в `%TEMP%\superpuperpacket\ `, и именно оттуда запускать (%TEMP% на каждой станции свой, и обычно он правильный - или то же в %SYSTEMROOT%\Temp, который гарантированно присутствует на любой машине).

Comment: Хотя список установленных программ можно получить и прямым доступом к удалённому реестру - будет такой доступ имеется.

Comment: `Aida64` вроде бы как умеет дёргать список софта по сети в редакции engineer.